# Need Voip call like in Uber in Flutter

Tags: flutter, call, voip

My app need a voip phone call to another person who is using this app and the phone number should not be the real phone number like in Uber. Can somebody please help, I searched in google and I could find nothing.

Comment: Did u make any progress on this ?

Comment: still working on to find the best solution, i need both server and app(in flutter), so got some leads if i am getting everything working i will come back here

Comment: Were you successful with it?

Comment: There are libraries present in flutter right now. I was not successful with this at that time

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to add this feture in my crrunt project and find **[zegocloud](https://www.zegocloud.com/?_source=google_sem&_keyword=zegocloud&_adsgroup=144412889488&_adscamp=17725850103&device=c&utm_term=zegocloud&utm_campaign=%E5%8D%B0%E5%BA%A6-%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81-Video%20Call-%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%E8%AF%8D&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=4689334831&hsa_cam=17725850103&hsa_grp=144412889488&hsa_ad=609878358879&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=kwd-1042015941298&hsa_kw=zegocloud&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgribBhDkARIsAASA5butg225HU2CvMPh7PR2adiWdYYNumEcSkmWkiaIvXwVKizx0j7aI5caAlbxEALw_wcB)** they have good documentation on how to implement voice/video calling one-on-one and group too.
Here's the [doc](https://docs.zegocloud.com/article/11892) and here's the code snippet of [basic](https://github.com/ZEGOCLOUD/zego_uikit_prebuilt_call_example_flutter/tree/master/call) implementation in the flutter.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best option is to go with an open source WebRTC based solution if you are ready to self host the VoIP server. In this case you can consider using Pion VoIP package which is available even in flutter. See https://github.com/pion/ion-sdk-flutter

To avoid hosting and ready to pay some cash for the calls users make, consider Twilio or any other cheaper alternatives which can do the hosting for you, but gives API calls to use them in your app.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Pion is active in their #slack channel. Most of my doubts cleared just there!

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest that you save the actual number with a key value pair example

```
{
 'cell':'0000000000',
 'fakeCell':'0123456789'
}
```

Then whenever you want to call through the app you do a quick lookup to get the real number.

also here is a [WebRTC Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc) you can use